# How to unit test embedded javascript which is being imported directly in a browser

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, codeigniter, jestjs

I have several javascript files wrote in a ["pre es6/module era"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781449393854/ch13s02.html#:%7E:text=Client%2Dside%20JavaScript%20code%20is,attribute%20of%20a%20tag) way. They are being used directly in pages from this application I am working (CodeIgniter 3). I import the files, directly in the pages (called views in CodeIgniter) usually like the example below and depending on the page being rendered different files are include.

```
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/home.js"></script>
```

What I want to do is to unit test the functions that are written on these files. The tests don't need to emulate the pages where they are being rendered, because I'm not gonna do functional tests for now, I just need to test the output of the functions in these files.

First I thought about using node/jest for the tests, but I am not sure of how I could import the code from the old files, without transforming them in modules, which is not an option.

Comment: This depends a lot on scripts themselves which you didn't present. But most times they aren't suitable for proper unit tests. You cannot access local variables that aren't exposed. Jest is module-oriented. *without transforming them in modules, which is not an option* - this is generally what UMD modules are for, this requires a specific adjustment that doesn't prevent scripts from being used in non-modular environment.

Comment: I'm looking for something similarly too.